# Unable to use php functions on hostgator server

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I write a php script and run it on hostgator server and it is giving this error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(
>   http://affiliates.kissmyads.com/stats/lead_report.json?api_key=AFFRd3xa8hRB3xOj7KsPnmQhlFYgNE&start_date=2014-06-24&end_date=2014-06-24)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in www/barpy-money.in/app/kissmyads.php on line 10

It is unable to load function file-get-contents(). I am using this function directly in my program. When I run this code in joomla article it works fine but on server it gives error. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

This is my code:

```
<?php

require_once 'include/DB_Connect.php';
    // connecting to database
    $db = new DB_Connect();
    $db->connect();

$url = ' http://affiliates.kissmyads.com/stats/lead_report.json?api_key=my_api_key&start_date=2014-06-24&end_date=2014-06-24';

$result = file_get_contents( $url ); // line number 10

echo '<pre>';
print_r( json_decode( $result ) );
echo '</pre>';  ?>
```

Comment: URLs usually don't start with a space character.

Comment: A poorly worded title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php.net documentation for this function has a tip at the bottom:

Tip
A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled. See fopen() for more details on how to specify the filename.

In order to do this you will need to edit your php.ini file. Per hostgators instructions:

allow_url_fopen, how to enable

This can be done via your php.ini file by adding the following line:

allow_url_fopen = On
The php.ini file is where you declare changes to your PHP settings. You can edit the existing php.ini, or create a new text file in any subdirectory and name it php.ini.

http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/allow_url_fopen-how-to-enable

Also you have a space in the $url variable before your http.

Answer (score 0):

check you have enabled in your php.ini

```
allow_url_fopen = on
```

try to check `phpinfo()`

or may be url doesn't exist you given in [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) also do not add spaces in url you need to set like:-

```
$url = "http://affiliates.kissmyads.com/stats/lead_report.json?api_key=my_api_key&start_date=2014-06-24&end_date=2014-06-24";
$result = file_get_contents($url);
```